# Is it possible to have the data directory outside Tomcat8?

Tags: tomcat8, dokuwiki

I am a newbie in Dokuwiki and i am facing a somehow complex problem. I am posting this message here because apparently I cannot post it on the official Dokuwiki forum because my message it's always treated as "Spam". Pleas help me

I habe been ordered to find a solution to the following problem. I need to move the data directory (inside ../tomcat_dir/mydokuwiki/dokuwiki/data) to another path (f.e. d:/test/prueba)

I've already tried to add a context in Tomcat's server xml such as:

Context docBase="d:\test\data" path="new_data"

but i do not where should I reference this "new_data" path variable.

I also have no idea if my approach is correct, anyway.

Believe me people, any help on this matter will be be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: DokuWiki seems PHP application and has nothing to Tomcat. What is EXACTLY Your situation?

Comment: The data directory is served from the following path C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\p5dokuwiki\dokuwiki\data. I would like to serve this "data" directory from d:\test\data for instance

Comment: Want "help on this matter will be be much appreciated" so let community to know excactly problem. Now many, many details are unknown.

Comment: I only want to move the "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\p5dokuwiki\dokuwiki\data" to another location and not receiving the 404 message when I access Dokuwiki through the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location of the data directory with the ['savedir' config option](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:savedir). The folder can be moved anywhere, it only needs to be writable by Tomcat.